# Canaan's age when cursed

Tags: parashat-noach, age, curse, noach-noah-the-man

When Noah cursed Canaan in [Genesis 9:25](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0109.htm#25), was Canaan a full grown adult?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. I can't quite tell what you're asking here. What does the last sentence mean?

Comment: In short, is it possible that the grandsons of Noah could have been born before the flood, assuming Noah cursed Canaan when Canaan was of an adult age.

Comment: @Luise, you seem to be asking multiple questions here: how old Canaan was, and whether or not Genesis cares how old Noah's grandchildren were post-Flood. Did I get that right? ....if so, please consider picking one of them, and posting the other as a separate question: generally speaking, we prefer having [one question per question post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735/266359), to make it fair to those answering.

Comment: Note that this must have been after the vines grew, matured, and were able to make wine. Even though the growth was miraculous, it still must have been some time after they left the Ark.